# Javascript do not get incremented variable value instead it use defined value

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code I used JQuery with javascript first I defined room variable as `0`. But inside the add_fields function I increment the room variable. `add_fields` function only works when user clicks a button.

But in keyup method in Jquery always gets the room as 0 because I defined it in the code. Although after I click the button and run add_fields function the room variable increased (I checked it inside the function by `console.log(room)`) but keyup method still see it as `0`.

Help me out please.

```
var room = 0;

$('#room_fileds').on('keyup', '.item_name' + room + '', function() {
    var query = $(this).val();

    if (query != '') {
        var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('FoodItemController.fetchNameWhenType')}}",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                query: query,
                _token: _token
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#name_list' + room + '').fadeIn();
                $('#name_list' + room + '').html(data);
            }
        })
    }
});

//set item-id when user selcts the item name from the dropdown list
$(document).on('click', '#list2', function() {
    $('.item_name' + room + '').val($(this).text());
    $('#name_list' + room + '').fadeOut();
});

function add_fields() {
    room++;

    var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col"><label>Ingrediants</label><input type ="text" placeholder="Item" name="ingri[' + room + ']" class="form-control item_name' + room + ' "><div id="name_list' + room + '" style="z-index: 1;position:absolute;"></div>   </div><div class="form-group col"><label>Amounts</label><input type ="text" placeholder="Amounts" name="amount[' + room + ']" class="form-control"></div><div class="col form-group"><a type="button" id="clickR[' + room + ']" class="btn-floating cyan"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a type="button" id="clickX[' + room + ']" class="btn-floating cyan"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div></div>';
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
    document.getElementById('length').value = room + 1;
    var hello = document.getElementById("length").value
}
```

Comment: after clicking on add_fields are you getting updated value or same value?

Comment: It getting updated as room = 1 and so on. But 
$('#room_fileds').on('keyup', '.item_name' + room + '', function() this function getting room as 0.

Comment: make a fiddle we will check